# Scale a fit shape graph with Vega

Tags: javascript, topojson, vega

I am using Vega (V5) to render Topojson of a building with a 9 precision depth (about a meter scale). My three base requirements are to:

- Center and scale to the building
- Angle/rotate the building so the entrance shows at the bottom of the graph
- Allow the user to zoom and pan within the bounds of the building (bbox of the topojson)

I can easily do all of these things independently with Vega in a projection. I can center and scale with `"fit"` and `"size"`. I can then angle with `"rotate": [0, 0, myAngle]`, I can save this angle externally. This visually looks perfect but because fit locks in scale and translate I can not adjust them with signals, preventing any zoom and pan features.

So my questions is one of the following:

- What is the official, *correct*, way to scale a fit shape graph (may not be possible)
- How do you replicate `fit` and `size` logic with other fields and values. (something happens with fit that lets rotate only affect the bound box, vs the world)

I am working in a JavaScript environment so I can do calculations externally on the Topojson. I would prefer a solution that works within pure Vega specification but a JS solution would be gladly excepted as an alternative answer (assuming there truly is no Vega solution at this time).

Comment: I have the same problem. If you found a solution I will be glad to hear it as well :)

Comment: @theFrok Unfortunately we dropped Vega in favor for pure D3. While we liked Vega it was just too new and feature incomplete for our level of need.